# c# bool function working principle

Tags: c#, arrays, function, boolean

Can anyone explain me the principle of how this code works? I asked for help from 1 of my teachers, he wrote the code and I have no idea what he ment with that.

So I have a bool function, that returns false or true value (obviously). But the thing is that, there's this line of code:

```
while (!DrikstPievienot(skaitlis, i, j, numbers));
```

What does it mean? The code will work while the bool function will keep returning false value?

Comment: Just to make sure, there's no line with "`do`" somewhere earlier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is not really a good example

The while statement is followed by a semicolon. The input parameters to the underlying function seems to be constant (unless there is some reference type passed in), and so, if nothing happens inside the function that could change the return value, this loop executes forever or never

So expanding the above code you have

```
while (false == DrikstPievienot(skaitlis, i, j, numbers));
```

meaning that if the called method return false the while statement evaluates to

```
while(false == false);
```

and this runs for eons (or until a power outages shut down everything)

Comment: Of course that's true, but, as is,  I can't tell anything about this. And I am still very unconfortable with that semicolon. However I add your observation to the answer above.

Answer (score 4):

> The code will work while the bool function will keep returning false
>   value

Yes, the while loop will continue while `DrikstPievienot` method continues to return `false`.

If the method returns `true` once, then the it will break out of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 2):

*"The code will work while the bool function will keep returning false value?"*

Yes, exactly because while it is returning false, the while loop 
condition will keep evaluating to true. So you got it right.

For more details you may want to check this link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2aeyhxcd.aspx

Answer (score 1):

To understand it more, if you write "while" and press the "Tab" button twice this code snippet will show up:

```
while (true)
{

}
```

this means the while loop will function as long as the condition it's checking is true, your teacher added "!" to make the while loop function ONLY if the return value is false.

Look at it from a different way, say you have

```
bool isTrue = true;
while (isTrue);
```

let's modify the code a bit:

```
bool isTrue = DrikstPievienot(skaitlis, i, j, numbers);
while (isTrue)
```

Now as you know replacing "isTrue" with your function name in the while loop (like your teacher wrote) will give the same result as using the "isTrue" variable in the while loop. (again your teacher added "!" to make the while loop function ONLY if the return value is false.)

Answer (score 0):

A while loop will continue until a condition is met.

The while loop:

```
while (!DrikstPievienot(skaitlis, i, j, numbers));
```

is calling a function `DrikstPievienot` which returns a bool. But the function is prefixed with '!' Not. This means the loop should continue until it returns true.

Answer (score 0):

For better understanding you can translate it like this, `while not true do s.t.`, I think if you see it this way it'll make much more sense.